# In Angular styles.scss @extend element with imported css library?

Tags: angular, sass

What I want to do in the `styles.scss` file is:

```
@import '~tachyons/css/tachyons.css';

body {
  @extend .w-100;
}
```

But when I call ng serve it fails with:

`"body" failed to @extend ".w-100". The selector ".w-100" was not found.`

But the class `.w-100` exists in tachyons css library.  How to do it correctly? (Note: I am using Angular 7)

Comment: @extend is only for sass? if you want the style, just add w-100 to body class list.

Comment: extend works with css classes as well. I just wanted to find a general approach to create in my styles.scss file all sorts of mixins and classes derived from tachyons css library.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

Instead of importing the css version of tachyons, I had to import the sass version.

```
@import '~tachyons-sass/tachyons.scss';

body {
  @extend .w-100;
}
```

It seems it has something to do with the sass-loader itself?
Anyways, now it works.

Comment: Thanks Dachstein. Been trying to find this.

Comment: Glad this post was helpful not only to me :)